# Select redundant rows only, not the original

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm tasked with cleaning up a system that has generated redundant orders.

Data example of the problem

```
ORDER ID, SERIAL, ...
1         1
2         1
3         2
4         2
5         3
6         3
7         3
```

The above data shows that 2 orders were generated with serial 1, 2 orders with serial 2, and 3 orders with serial 3. This is not allowed, and there should be only one order per serial.

So I need a query that can identify the REDUNDANT orders ONLY. I'd like the query to exclude the original order.

So the output from the above data should be:

```
REDUNDANT ORDER IDS
2
4
6
7
```

I can easily identify which orders have duplicates using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` but the tricky part comes with removing the original.

Is it even possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As Thomas hints at, not really sure how I can use the linked question; it seems somewhat different that my needs.

Comment: @ThomasG Your mention of MIN gave me an idea, and I think I'll be able to solve it using a self join. I can only give you an upvote, so I'll do that.

Comment: @ThomasG At it's most basic, it's hardly a stretch: `DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id NOT IN (...)`

Comment: @DarkNeuron your answer is here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a918/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted in the comments, here's one way to achieve this:

```
SELECT T1.ORDER_ID as redundant
FROM thetable T1
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT SERIAL, MIN(ORDER_ID) AS firstorder
  FROM thetable
  GROUP BY SERIAL
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) T2 ON T1.ORDER_ID=T2.firstorder
WHERE T2.firstorder IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a918/3)